# LibGDX FitViewport doesn't fit itself on construction, but it does on resize

Tags: java, libgdx, viewport, window-resize

I'm racking my brain trying to figure out what's going on here... I'm using a FitViewport which is working great whenever I resize the screen, but when it's first created during the constructor it doesn't fit itself into the screen like it's supposed to (and like it does when I resize).

Here's the code for my constructor and for the resize() method:

```
public class UpgradesScreen implements Screen {

    private ScreenHandler sh;

    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Viewport viewport;

    public UpgradesScreen(ScreenHandler sh) {

        Gdx.app.log("UpgradesScreen", "Attached");

        this.sh = sh;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, sh.V_WIDTH, sh.V_HEIGHT);

        viewport = new FitViewport(sh.V_WIDTH, sh.V_HEIGHT, cam);
        viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        Gdx.app.log("UpgradesScreen", "resizing");
        viewport.update((int) width, (int) height);
    }
```

I've checked to make sure that Gdx.graphics.getWidth() gives the same figure as the 'width' argument the resize() method receives when I resize the screen (likewise with the 'height' values).

As far as I can tell the viewport should behave exactly the same during the constructor as it does when I resize. So why is it being stubborn and not updating to fit?

Here's what it looks like after I resize:

[image: FitViewport after resize]

...and here's what it looks like when the screen is first created, before the window gets manually resized:

[image]

Comment: Note: I tried adding the viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()); line into the show() method just in case that was needed... Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you show your drawing code?

Comment: It's pretty extensive, and not really related. It just uses standard coords within the virtual width and height of 960 and 600, and when the window is resized the FitViewport renders it all perfectly. The problem is just that the FitViewport isn't being updated or applied when it's first created so I need to figure out why and how to make it do so.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Viewport` object which is not being used at all at start.

Call

```
viewport.apply();
```

Before your draw calls.

---

Also, `resize` method is called at start by default. Use it to initialize game objects in stead of constructor.

---

**Edit:**
Have a look at [LibGDX Lifecycle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle).

`resize` is always called before `render`. There should not be different behavior at start and afterwards. That is your root problem. Try fixing it first.

Comment: Hmm where should I put that? I changed the .replace() line right after the initialization to .apply() and it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Call apply method just before your draw calls.

Comment: Hmm okay.. Seems like putting the .apply() in the render() method is inviting a lot of redundant overhead given that it only needs to do the .apply() on the very first loop. In the meantime I've wrapped it in a boolean that gets toggled when it runs, so instead of doing the .apply() 60 times a second it just does a bool check, though I feel like there should be a more elegant way of ensuring the .apply() on happens on the first run.

Comment: Either way thanks for that suggestion. Having .apply() in the render() loop does indeed fix the problem :)

Comment: "resize is always called before render. There should not be different behavior at start and afterwards. That is your root problem. Try fixing it first." -- exactly, so what would be stopping the resize() from being called without manually resizing the window?

Comment: It's impossible to speculate without looking at any code. I suggest you to run your code in debugger mode, put breakpoints and see which order the method calls are following. If you stumble upon some difficulty after that, I believe that could result in a very good new question. Wish you best of luck.